# How to get list of video responses YouTube API Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube-api, response

I'm trying to get the list of videos returned from querying the URL of video responses in my app, but I can't seem to find any documentation on the topic especially for Objective C. I can get the url of the response list (see code below), but what kind of GData class do I use to have the url return a list of entries or videos in an array or list?

```
//get video object and get the link from it
GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *video = [videoList objectAtIndex:i];
GDataLink *vidResponses = video.videoResponsesLink;

//resulting link returns an xml feed
vidResponses= https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/luCT5A02n5w/responses
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the completion handler, the feed variable will be a **GDataFeedYouTubeVideo**, which has a property called **entries**, which is an array of **GDataEntryYouTubeVideo**s

```
GDataQueryYouTube * query = [[GDataQueryYouTube alloc] init];

query.feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/luCT5A02n5w/responses"];

GDataServiceGoogleYouTube * service = [[GDataServiceGoogleYouTube alloc] init];

service.userAgent = @"App Name";

[service fetchFeedWithQuery:query
                      completionHandler:^(GDataServiceTicket *ticket, GDataFeedBase *feed, NSError *error)
 {
     if(!error)
     {
         NSArray * entries = feed.entries;

         if(entries.count)
         {
             GDataEntryYouTubeVideo * firstVideo = entries[0];
         }
     }
 }];
```

It appears that URL has no video responses.

Comment: Hey that worked great, I had to go and add some responses to another url and that seems to be working. Thanks!